# Script works fine in Rstudio but not in Rscript

Tags: r

I would like to schedule a R script which works fine via Rstudio. But when try to run the script with Rscript I got an error. The script take some parameters in a csv file and try to gather data on opentsdb.

```
library(devtools)
install_local("/home/me/Downloads/opentsdbr-master")
install_local("/home/me/Downloads/nomalyDetection-master")
install_local("/home/me/Downloads/anomalydots", force="TRUE")
install_local("/home/me/Downloads/RAD")
library(reticulate)
library(anomalydots)
lbrary('methods')

l <- read.csv(file = "/home/bbtex/Downloads/metrics_list.csv", sep = ",")
n <- length(l$metrics)
for (i in 1:n){
  tag=as.character(l$tags[i])
  metric=as.character(l$metrics[i])
  tag=eval(parse(text=paste("c(",tag,")",sep="")))
  newdata=getTsOpenTSDBOptimized(metric=metric,hostname="opentsdb-read.intcs.meshcore.net",port=4242,downsample=10,endDate=as.character(Sys.Date()),agg=l$agg[i],tags=tag)
  newdata = anomalydots::fillHoles2(newdata)
  newdata = anomalydots::timeSeriePreparation(newdata)
  timeseries[[i]] <- newdata
}
print ("Upload completed successfully")
```

When I run the following code with Rscript I have the following error:

> Error in tsd_get_ascii(metric, interval, tags, agg, rate, downsample, 
>   : 
>       Calls: getTsOpenTSDBOptimized -> getTsOpenTSDB -> tsd_get -> tsd_get_ascii
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In tsd_get_ascii(metric, interval, tags, agg, rate, downsample,  :
>         Response code 503
>       2: In tsd_get_ascii(metric, interval, tags, agg, rate, downsample,  :
>         URL: http://opentsdb-read.intcs.meshcore.net:4242/q?start=2018%2F10%2F19-02%3A00%3A00&m=avg%3A600s-sum%3Adb.mysql.threads_connected%7Bhost%3Dbpct4005s%7D&end=2018%2F10%2F22-01%3A59%3A59&ascii=
>       Execution halted

When I follow the link in the error, I can see the data printed in the webpage.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: [HTTP 503](https://httpstatuses.com/503) suggests the server is (perhaps temporarily) overloaded. It may also suggest that your script is trying to connect too many times within a set period, though other statuses might be more appropriate for that. You might want to check the API and terms of service to find out if they have connection limitations (e.g., max 'x' connections per hour).

Comment: Welcome to SO. `devtools::install_local()` is going to _reinstall the package every time that script runs_. That sounds like a really bad idea and if any part of that installation process calls out to the OSTDB server it may be triggering an automatic threshold rejection. You should likely add some code to test of the packages are installed already and not just wantonly install them every time.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But I don't understand why the same script works fine in Rstudio and why the data is printed on the webpage when I follow the link in the error.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm trying your suggestion and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Hello, I removed the proxy environment variable and the script finally worked.